# Woocommerce Subscription Cancellation (Send customer email)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

Woocommerce subscriptions by default doesn't send subscription cancellation to the customer so I'm trying to add that by using `woocommerce_subscription_status_pending-cancel`Hook and the function is below:

```
add_action('woocommerce_subscription_status_pending-cancel', 'yanco_woocommerce_subscription_status_pending_cancel', 10, 3 );
function yanco_woocommerce_subscription_status_pending_cancel( $subscription ) {
    $customer_email = $subscription->get_billing_email();
    $wc_emails = WC()->mailer()->get_emails();

    $admin_email = $wc_emails['WCS_Email_Cancelled_Subscription']->recipient;
    $wc_emails['WCS_Email_Cancelled_Subscription']->trigger( $subscription );

    $wc_emails['WCS_Email_Cancelled_Subscription']->recipient = $customer_email;
    $wc_emails['WCS_Email_Cancelled_Subscription']->trigger( $subscription );
}
```

But this code isn't working when I click on the Cancel button in my account it keep circling without any response after a refresh it cancels the subscription but not sending email to customer.

I tried adding the code above and was expecting the emails to be sent out to the customer when they cancel their subscription.

Answer (score 0):

This has fixed the issue:

```
function set_customer_as_cancelled_subscription_recipient($recipient, $subscription) {
    return $subscription ? $subscription->get_billing_email() : $recipient;
}`
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 0):

Your suggested `add_filter('woocommerce_email_recipient_cancelled_subscription'`
filter is what I found works as well.

One possible modification: If you want to send the cancel email to the customer PLUS still send it  to whoever you have set as the recipient in WooCommerce Email Settings (such as an internal admin user for example), this works:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_email_recipient_cancelled_subscription', 'set_customer_as_cancelled_subscription_recipient', 10, 2);
function set_customer_as_cancelled_subscription_recipient($recipient, $subscription) {

    // Append the customer's billing email if it's not already in the recipient list in addition to the recipient specified in WooCommerce Email settings
    if ($subscription && false === strpos($recipient, $subscription->get_billing_email())) {
        $recipient .= ',' . $subscription->get_billing_email();
    }
    return $recipient;
}
```